# MVC Route parameters with dashes

Tags: c#, redirect, routes, controllers

I have problem with my routing in MVC5 application.

I hava a lot of routes defined and i don's use MapMvcAttributeRoutes.

```
        // redirect module
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Redirect",
            url: "{category}/{product}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectUrl", product = UrlParameter.Optional, culture = String.Empty },
            constraints: new { category = @"^(?!Category$|Content$)(\w{3,})$" }
        );            

        // --------- DEFAULT ---------
        // should be always at the end
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, culture = String.Empty },
            constraints: new { controller = @"\w{3,}" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultLang",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = @"\w{2}" }
        );
```

I want to "Redirect" route catch address like "/same-day/red-car". But the main problem is dashes. When I replaced dashes with underscore it's working.

Please send mi some suggestions.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Why "/same-day" is "controller" parameter and "/same_day" is "category" parameter?